# Facebook timeline brand pages change width

Tags: resize, facebook-javascript-sdk

Does anybody knows...
How to make the width of the new brand pages tabs/apps to 810px.
I cant make it change from the old size of 520px

I tried FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow, FB.Canvas.setSize () but no success

thanks
EB

Answer (score 2):

There is a option in the App Settings to change too.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Edit settings of your app and check under the Page Option and then select Wide.
Facebook is setting max width as per the option.
Tho I imagine the default changes for (new) apps come the end of March

[image]